# How to cut the top corner of UIView with a rect of another UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How can I cut a view with rect of another view at a specific point?

[image: Required Result]

These are two views

1. UIImageView which is showing an image.
2. UIView with a background color which is showing the status of a user.

Note: Both the views will be in uniform size w.r.t height and width.

A working example would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: you just put other view up side of image view.

Comment: I need a cutting effect on the top right corner as shown in the image.

Comment: yes it should possible with object have border that type that you need.

Comment: I dont need a border i need this cutting effect because background can be of any color and it needs to be visible via that cut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
 -(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    UIImageView* yourView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 200, 200)];
    yourView.center = self.view.center;
    yourView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg"];

    yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 100;
    yourView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.view addSubview: yourView];

    NSUInteger radius = 50;
    UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius) cornerRadius:radius];

    UIBezierPath *path =  [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:yourView];
    [path appendPath:circlePath];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;

    yourView.layer.mask  = maskLayer;

    UIImageView* smallView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yourView.frame.origin.x + 8 ,
                                                                           yourView.frame.origin.y + 8 , 80, 80)];
    smallView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg"];
    smallView.layer.cornerRadius = 40;
    smallView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:smallView];

}
```

[image]Add mask to layer.

Comment: what is `yourView` and what is `tView`?

Comment: Sorry, no tView. yourView is "UIImageView which is showing an image".

Comment: It is working for me. Added extended code and result of it's work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by taking two `UIView`s

Place first `UIView` at top right corner of the `UIImageView` and give its background color which similar to `self.view` background color. In your case it is blue. And yeah also make this view rounded by setting corner radius.

Now place second view in the first view and give its background color and also set corner radius to make it circular.

You have too do some calculations so your view will appear at required place. And also make sure that your inner view must be at centre of the outer view. You will definitely get the desired result.

Comment: I don’t want to handle it with a background color